# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[__NSCFString scheme]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to open a url in iPhone default browser I did this. The code is actually supposed to get the url from an object based on a selected item in tableview

```
BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:blogPost.url];
```

When I run the app i get the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString scheme]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febb263ba30'

I then set an Exception break point, the app crashes at the third line of code displaying the error.
What should I do?

Comment: [[application openURL : blogPost.rl] stringvalue] you have to cast it into string.

Comment: @Chandra But blogPost.url in not a NSString?

Comment: `blogPost.url` seems to be a `NSString` rather than the expected `NSURL`

Comment: @Israel can you debug your code? After the first line is correct the content of blogPost?

Answer (score 2):

**Try like this**

```
[application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

**Make sure**

**blogPost.url** is a NSUrl

Note: if  **blogPost.url** is NSString type

```
[application openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:blogPost.url]];
```

The crash report clearly says that you are trying to pass **NSString** type value instead of passing **NSUrl** type value. That is type mismatch of argument *blogPost.url*

Comment: I found the solution. blogPost.url was set like this before blogPost.url = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]; so I changed it to this blogPost.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"url"]];